# How to extract `Pr(>F)` from `leveneTest()`?

Tags: r

```
> leveneTest(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,na.action='na.omit')
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median: "na.omit")
       Df F value   Pr(>F)   
group   2  6.3527 0.002259 **
      147                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

After `leveneTest()`,I checked the result structure as below:

```
> leveneTest(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,na.action='na.omit') %>% str
Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Df     : int  2 147
 $ F value: num  6.35 NA
 $ Pr(>F) : num  0.00226 NA
 - attr(*, "heading")= chr "Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median: \"na.omit\")"
```

Then I extract `Pr(>F)`,but got error as below:

```
> leveneTest(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,na.action='na.omit')$Pr(>F)
Error: unexpected '>' in "leveneTest(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,na.action='na.omit')$Pr(>"
```

What's the problem?How to extract `Pr(>F)`?

Comment: `broom::tidy()` if you're feeling lazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual `x$Pr(>F)` won't work because `>` is a special character, so you need `x[["Pr(>F)"]]` or `` x$`Pr(>F)` ``

Note that the vector you get out has the value you want followed by an `NA` (i.e. `c(0.002258528,NA)`

Comment: `myp2<-lapply(models,function(x)x$"Pr(>F)")` how can i put the p value threshold condition to this line of code my idea to filter those models which are significant such as less than 0.05..

Comment: this might deserve to be a separate question, but `pvals <- sapply(models,function(x)x[["Pr(>F)"]][1]); which(pvals<0.05)` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I did ask here i was looking for possible solution i came across your answer  i would like and request you to answer my query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130217/how-to-filter-a-list-of-models-based-on-prf?noredirect=1#comment127447549_72130217